# Xcode on Windows

Tags: xcode, windows

What are the disadvantage of working with Xcode on Windows? What problems do I encounter from the beginning to the end (upload to the market) of the application development process?

Comment: Just asking! did you installed xcode in windows ?

Comment: Oh no, i'm investigating for now

Answer (score 1):

I wasn’t aware you could run Xcode natively on Windows. There are a number of ways of creating the code in Xamarin for example, but I think you still need a Mac to do the code signing/uploading to the App Store.  Have you read https://codewithchris.com/xcode-for-windows/ ? Some good ideas on there to try, although I ended up buying a secondhand MBP as it worked out just as easy...

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did research on installation on the internet but i could not find an explanation for the whole process

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Virtual Box and Hackintosh to Virtualize a mac.
I don't know if it helps but you could try it.
https://www.virtualbox.org/

https://hackintosh.com/